# displaying play,pause buttons over picture box dynamically,in .net compact framework

Tags: compact-framework

I have two picture box to display some pictures at regular intervals in .net compact framework.

I need to show toolbar with play,pause buttons when i touch the respective picture boxes and hide when i touch the other one..

Answer (score 0):

So what, exactly, is the question?  You could use a third picturebox to hold your "toolbar" and display/hide it as necessary, or make the toolbar a user control so you can easily add in separate buttons.

Comment: Exactly, just add an Click event handler to the PictureBox which then shows/hides the toolbar control as required.